# Navigate to particular page in ionic from javascript after reciving push notification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am writing a push notification receiver using phonegap push plugin .All things working fine i am receiving push notification from server but the problem is when i clicked on notification received it redirects me to my application home page instead of that i want it should redirect to notification detail page .I am using ui-router in my app all state are configured properly but i dont know how to call a ui-route from external javascript.

```
   var connectionStatus;
     var push;
    var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
 onDeviceReady: function() { 

     push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
            "senderID": "XXXXXXXX",
             "iconColor": "red"
        },
        "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, 
        "windows": {} 
    });

    push.on('registration', function(data) {

        console.log("registration event");

        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
         angular.element(document.body).injector().get("RegistrationService").post_reg(data.registrationId);

    });

    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log("notification event");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        //here i need to navigate to notification detail page 
    });

    push.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("push error");
    });


    }
 };

 app.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
push.on('notification', function(data) {
    console.log("notification event");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    $location.url('url') 
});
```